# get p value and r value from HuberRegressor in Sklearn

Tags: python, regression, robust

I have datasets with some outliers.
From the simple linear regression, using

```
stat_lin = stats.linregress(X, Y)
```

I can get coefficient, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err

But I want to apply robust regression method as I don't want to include outliers.

So I applied Huber regressor from Sklearn,

```
huber = linear_model.HuberRegressor(alpha=0.0, epsilon=1.35)
huber.fit(mn_all_df['X'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1), mn_all_df['Y'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
```

from that, I can get, coefficient, intercept, scale, outliers.

I am happy with the result as the coefficient value is higher and the regression line is fitting with the majority of the data points.

However, I need a values such as r value and p value to say, the results from huber regressor is significant.

How can I get r value and p value from the robust regression (my case, using huber regressor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [robust linear models in statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/rlm.html). For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets

x = iris.data[:,0]
y = iris.data[:,2]
rlm_model = sm.RLM(y, sm.add_constant(x),
M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()
```

The p value you get from scipy.lingress is the p-value that the slope is not zero, this you can get by doing:

```
rlm_results.summary()
                     
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -7.1311      0.539    -13.241      0.000      -8.187      -6.076
x1             1.8648      0.091     20.434      0.000       1.686       2.044
==============================================================================
```

Now the r_value from lingress is a correlation coefficient and it stays as that. With robust linear model, you are weighing your observations differently, hence making it less sensitive to outliers, therefore, the r squared calculation does not make sense here. You might get a lower r squared since you are avoiding the line towards the outlier data points.

See comments by @Josef (who maintains statsmodels) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655196/how-to-get-r-squared-for-robust-regression-rlm-in-statsmodels), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073531/is-it-appropriate-to-calculate-r-squared-of-robust-regression-using-rlm). You can try [this calculation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83826/is-a-weighted-r2-in-robust-linear-model-meaningful-for-goodness-of-fit-analys) if you would like a meaningful r-squared

[How to get R-squared for robust regression (RLM) in Statsmodels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655196/how-to-get-r-squared-for-robust-regression-rlm-in-statsmodels)

Comment: It's absolutely brilliant method

Answer (score 2):

With the `HuberRegressor` you use `sklearn`, which does not offer methods for r_value and p_value in their `linear_model` module. There are other answers which calculate these values from the results of a regression.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677750/7947994) someone shows how the p_values of a linear regression can be calculated. I think this can also be applied with your model.

Edit: I looked into the r value, which is used to calculate the r squared value by squaring it. Following snipped is from the [documentation of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html):

```
print(f"R-squared: {res.rvalue**2:.6f}")
R-squared: 0.717533
```

If you have your own regression, you can use this method of sklearn to calculate the r squared value: [`sklearn.metrics.r2score(y_true, y_pred)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html).